Скрипты JS Cookie Работают на ПК нормально, но на телефоне - нет
Для сайта с орендой яхт, клиент захотел что бы на странице Спасиба вам, была некоторая информация об заказе, с одной страницы берется информация про дни оренды на след. выводится, на пк и планшетах все работает так как нужно, но на телефонах - нет. Я даже localStorage юзал, но тоже самое, на телефонах кидает null, как решить данную проблему?
Код с секции со страницы где берется информация:
// Function to set a cookie
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}

// Function to get a cookie
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

// Define the event handler function
function handleClick() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        const productUrl = window.location.pathname;
        const productHandle = productUrl.split('/').filter(part => part).pop();
        // Store product handle in cookie
        setCookie('selectedProductHandle', productHandle, 1);
        console.log("Product handle set in cookie:", productHandle);
        // Redirect to the thank you page
        window.location.href = '{{ shop.url }}/pages/thank-you';
    }, 2000);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function searchButton() {
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bookeasy-next-btn');
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            if (buttons[i].innerText.trim() === 'Confirm') {
                buttons[i].classList.add('gotchya');
                buttons[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick); // Add event listener
            } else {
                buttons[i].classList.remove('gotchya');
                buttons[i].removeEventListener('click', handleClick); // Remove event listener
            }
        }
    }

    function searchDays() {
        numberOfDaysBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".bookeasy-booking-date-details");
        console.log("Day block found: " + numberOfDaysBlock.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDaysBlock.length; i++) {
            const bookingDate = numberOfDaysBlock[i].textContent;
            numberOfDaysText = numberOfDaysBlock[i].textContent.trim();

            const bookingDatesText = numberOfDaysBlock[i].textContent;
            const bookingDatesArray = bookingDatesText.split(', ');
            const numberOfDays = bookingDatesArray.length / 2;

            setCookie('selectedNumberOfDays', numberOfDays, 1);
            setCookie('selectedBookingDays', bookingDate, 1);
            console.log("Number of days set in cookie:", numberOfDays);
            console.log("Booking days set in cookie:", bookingDate);
        }
    }

    var searchIntervalConfirm = setInterval(searchButton, 500);
    var searchDaysElement = setInterval(searchDays, 500);
});
</script>

Код страницы Thank you:
// Function to get a cookie
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
    // Retrieve data from cookies
    const productHandle = getCookie('selectedProductHandle');
    const numberOfDays = getCookie('selectedNumberOfDays');
    const bookingDate = getCookie('selectedBookingDays');
    console.log("Retrieved product handle from cookie:", productHandle);
    console.log("Retrieved number of days from cookie:", numberOfDays);
    console.log("Retrieved booking date from cookie:", bookingDate);

    if (productHandle) {
        try {
            // Fetch product details using Shopify's Storefront API or AJAX request
            const productResponse = await fetch(`/products/${productHandle}.js`);
            const product = await productResponse.json();

            // Assuming the first variant is the one to be added to the cart
            const productVariantId = product.variants[0].id;

            const totalPrice = numberOfDays * product.price * 0.01;

            const formattedPrice = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'EUR',
                minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }).format(totalPrice);

            // Create a checkout button
            const checkoutButton = document.createElement('button');
            const mainButton = document.createElement('button');
            const bookingInfoText = document.createElement('div');
            bookingInfoText.classList.add("booking-info-text"); 
            bookingInfoText.innerHTML = `
                <div class="big-colored-text"><span>Yacht: </span>${product.title}</div>
                <div><span>Booking date: </span>${bookingDate}</div>
                <div class="big-colored-text"><span>Price: </span>${formattedPrice}</div>
            `;
            checkoutButton.classList.add("custom-checkout");     
            mainButton.classList.add("main-button"); 
            mainButton.innerHTML = 'To main';
            checkoutButton.innerHTML = 'Pay<span class="pal">Pal</span>';
            document.querySelector('.h0').innerHTML = `Thank You for booking<br>${product.title}`;

            // Add event listener to the checkout button
            mainButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                window.location.href = '/';
            });       
            checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const checkoutUrl = `/cart/${productVariantId}:${numberOfDays}`;
                window.location.href = checkoutUrl;
            });
            document.getElementById('place-self-start-custom').appendChild(bookingInfoText);
            document.getElementById('place-self-start-custom').appendChild(mainButton);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching product details:", error);
        }
    }
});
</script>

